# How can I remove all characters up to and including the 3rd slash in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm having trouble with removing all characters up to and including the 3 third slash in JavaScript.  This is my string:

```
http://blablab/test
```

The result should be:

```
test
```

Does anybody know the correct solution?

Comment: Do you always the need the text after the LAST slash or after the THIRD slash?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**To get the last item in a path,** you can split the string on `/` and then `pop()`:

```
var url = "http://blablab/test";
alert(url.split("/").pop());
//-> "test"
```

**To specify an individual part of a path**, split on `/` and use bracket notation to access the item:

```
var url = "http://blablab/test/page.php";
alert(url.split("/")[3]);
//-> "test"
```

**Or, if you want *everything* after the third slash**, `split()`, `slice()` and `join()`:

```
var url = "http://blablab/test/page.php";
alert(url.split("/").slice(3).join("/"));
//-> "test/page.php"
```

Comment: Keep in mind if there is a fourth slash, `pop` this will get everything after the last slash and `[3]` will get everthing between the third and fourth slashes.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response this answer helped my sory for the noobish question ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
var string = 'http://blablab/test'
string = string.replace(/[\s\S]*\//,'').replace(/[\s\S]*\//,'').replace(/[\s\S]*\//,'')
alert(string)
```

This is a regular expression. I will explain below

The regex is `/[\s\S]*\//`

`/` is the start of the regex

Where `[\s\S]` means whitespace or non whitespace (anything), not to be confused with `.` which does not match line breaks (`.` is the same as `[^\r\n]`).

`*` means that we match anywhere from zero to unlimited number of `[\s\S]`

`\/` Means match a slash character

The last `/` is the end of the regex

Comment: 3 regular expression replaces probably isn't the most efficient approach.

Comment: I know, I like regex allot but I did upvote the other answers knowing this.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "http://blablab/test";
var index = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    index = str.indexOf("/",index)+1;
}
str = str.substr(index);
```

To make it a one liner you could make the following:

```
str = str.substr(str.indexOf("/",str.indexOf("/",str.indexOf("/")+1)+1)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to split the string in parts and use `slice` to return all parts after the third slice.

```
var str = "http://blablab/test",
    arr = str.split("/");
arr = arr.slice(3);
console.log(arr.join("/"));  // "test"

// A longer string:
var str = "http://blablab/test/test";  // "test/test";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like this one:

```
'http://blablab/test'.match(/^(?:[^/]*\/){3}(.*)$/);
// -> ['http://blablab/test', 'test]
```

A string’s `match` method gives you either an array (of the whole match, in this case the whole input, and of any capture groups (and we want the first capture group)), or null. So, for general use you need to pull out the 1th element of the array, or null if a match wasn’t found:

```
var input = 'http://blablab/test',
    re = /^(?:[^/]*\/){3}(.*)$/,
    match = input.match(re),
    result = match && match[1]; // With this input, result contains "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "http://blablab/test";
let data = new URL(str).pathname.split("/").pop();
console.log(data);
```