# JavaScript indexOf() - how to get specific index

Tags: javascript, indexof

Let's say I have a URL:

```
http://something.com/somethingheretoo
```

and I want to get what's after the 3rd instance of `/`?

something like the equivalent of `indexOf()` which lets me input which instance of the backslash I want.

Comment: So what's the question? What have you tried? The question shows little or no effort from you.

Comment: I tried googling it, and got nothing.

Comment: Have you tried writing it yourself? :)

Comment: Look again at `indexOf()` (hint: it has an optional second parameter).

Comment: Are you simply trying to the the `pathname` portion of a url string?

Comment: For URIs, specifically, use `new URL("http://something.com/somethingheretoo").pathname` to get `"/somethingheretoo"`. Use `.slice(1)` to get just `"somethingheretoo"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know it starts with `http://` or `https://`, just skip past that part with this **one-liner**:

```
var content = aURL.substring(aURL.indexOf('/', 8));
```

This gives you more flexibility if there are multiple slashes in that segment you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
let s = 'http://something.com/somethingheretoo';
parts = s.split('/');
parts.splice(0, 2);
return parts.join('/');
```

Comment: After third `/` does not mean "between third and fourth"

Comment: See my comment below, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570276/javascript-indexof-how-to-get-specific-index/7570349#7570349.

Comment: Yes, I saw that before. That's why i changed my code. I delete the first elements of the string and join the end togther.

Comment: @PiTheNumber sorry to say that, but it seems like you haven't tested this piece of code.

Comment: @piotros yes, thanks! Still 3 upvotes!?! I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following function, which will return the index of the nth occurrence of the search string s, or -1 if there are n-1 or fewer matches.

```
String.prototype.nthIndexOf = function(s, n) {
  var i = -1;
  while(n-- > 0 && -1 != (i = this.indexOf(s, i+1)));
  return i;
}

var str = "some string to test";

alert(str.nthIndexOf("t", 3)); // 15
alert(str.nthIndexOf("t", 7)); // -1
alert(str.nthIndexOf("z", 4)); // -1

var sub = str.substr(str.nthIndexOf("t",3)); // "test"
```

Of course if you don't want to add the function to String.prototype you can have it as a stand-alone function by adding another parameter to pass in the string you want to search in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to `indexOf`:

```
var string = "http://something/sth1/sth2/sth3/"
var lastIndex = string.indexOf("/", lastIndex);
lastIndex = string.indexOf("/", lastIndex);
lastIndex = string.indexOf("/", lastIndex);
string = string.substr(lastIndex);
```

If you want to get the path of that given URL, you can also use a RE:

```
string = string.match(/\/\/[^\/]+\/(.+)?/)[1];
```

This RE searches for "`//`", accepts anything between "`//`" and the next "`/`", and returns an object. This object has several properties. propery `[1]` contains the substring after the third `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the Javascript "split" function:

```
var strWord = "me/you/something";
var splittedWord = strWord.split("/");
```

splittedWord[0] would return "me"

splittedWord[1] would return "you"

splittedWord[2] would return "something"

Comment: `var strWord = "me/you/something/haha"`. `splittedWord[3]` = "something", while the OP wants to match "something/haha".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the `pathname`. If you're in a browser, keep an `a` element handy...

```
var _a = document.createElement('a');
```

...and let it do the parsing for you.

```
_a.href = "http://something.com/somethingheretoo";

alert( _a.pathname.slice(1) );  // somethingheretoo
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2qT9c/

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could use the `lastIndexOf()` method to get the 3rd forward slash.

Comment: The last is not the same as the third, even if it seems so in the example.

Comment: Very true, but for OP's question, I made the assumption he wanted the last bit of the path and used the weasel phrase "In your case" :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very cool way of handling this:
[How can I remove all characters up to and including the 3rd slash in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965808/how-can-i-remove-all-characters-up-to-and-including-the-3rd-slash-in-a-string)

My preference of the proposed solutions is

```
var url = "http://blablab/test/page.php";
alert(url.split("/")[3]);
//-> "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inestead of using `indexOf` it is possible to do this this way:

```js
const url = 'http://something.com/somethingheretoo';
const content = new URL(url).pathname.slice(1);
```