# indexOf always gives start index of first occurence

Tags: javascript

I want a unique start and end index for every selected word or substring but using indexOf. Because indexOf always gives the first occurrence for repetitive words. Is there any way to get a unique index using indexOf only ?

Let say

var str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog barked, was it really lazy?"

So if I select "dog" then for the first dog start index will be (40) and for a second dog, it will be (52). but using indexOf only.

Your help will be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) thoroughly? Your example is exactly the same there. [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+string+indexof+from+specific+index) of [JavaScript indexOf() - how to get specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7570276/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog barked, was it really lazy?",
needle = 'dog',
var splitOnFound = string.split(needle).map(function (item)
{
    return this.pos += item.length + needle.length
}, {pos: -needle.length}).slice(0, -1);
console.log(splitOnFound);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. I want to use it using getSelection how will i use it in getSelection ?

Comment: when I select a dog then It gives me a unique index. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to use `indexOf`, the following should work.

```js
const str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog barked, was it really lazy?';

const findIndexesWithIndexOf = (str, subStr) => {
  let indices = [];
  if (str.length && subStr.length) {
    let lastIndex = 0;
    let remainingStr = str;

    do {
      lastIndex = remainingStr.indexOf(subStr); // Use of indexOf

      if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        remainingStr = remainingStr.slice(lastIndex + subStr.length);
        indices.push((indices[indices.length - 1] + subStr.length || 0) + lastIndex);
      }
    } while (remainingStr.length > subStr.length && lastIndex >= 0);
  }

  return indices;
};

console.log(findIndexesWithIndexOf(str, 'dog'));
```

Comment: Ok Ok i got it right. Thanks one more question can i save these indexes in db for matching nexttime ??will it work ?

Comment: Hey it's giving all together I want something like when I select the first dog it should give 40 similarly for the second dog can you please modify the code accordingly. I have do it based on user selection of word or substring. Thanks

Comment: It's giving me all occurrences I want only which one is selected using getSelection. using indexOf

Comment: function findIndexesWithIndexOf(str,subStr){
  let indices = [];
  if (str.length && subStr.length) {
    let lastIndex = 0;
    let remainingStr = str;

    // do {
      lastIndex = remainingStr.indexOf(subStr); // Use of indexOf

      if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        remainingStr = remainingStr.slice(lastIndex + subStr.length);
        indices = (indices[indices.length - 1] + subStr.length || 0) + lastIndex;
      }
    // } while (remainingStr.length > subStr.length && lastIndex >= 0);
  }

  return indices;
};

Comment: This codes me again for the first occurrence.I want for selected text not all occurences. please help